# Pie Chart 100% with androidplot

Tags: android, charts, pie-chart, androidplot

i have this pie chart in my app:

```
Segment seg0 = new Segment(" ", pgan);
Segment seg1 = new Segment(" ", pper);
Segment seg2 = new Segment(" ", pemp);

graficoPartidos.addSeries(seg0, new SegmentFormatter(Color.rgb(106, 168, 79), Color.BLACK,Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));

graficoPartidos.addSeries(seg1, new SegmentFormatter(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0), Color.BLACK,Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));

graficoPartidos.addSeries(seg2, new SegmentFormatter(Color.rgb(255, 153, 0), Color.BLACK,Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
```

where pgan, pper and pemp are Integers. If two of that numbers are 0, then the pie chart doesnt show anything and it suppose to show a full pie chart.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywIYP.png

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't see your problem here , can u show graficoPartidos declaration and assignment probably problem is there ?

Comment: PieChart graficoPartidos = (PieChart) promptGraf.findViewById(R.id.pieGoles);

graficoPartidos.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
   graficoPartidos.getRenderer(PieRenderer.class).setDonutSize((float) 0/100, PieRenderer.DonutMode.PERCENT);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, your code is fine.

It's just a bug in androidplot. At least in the last version - `0.6.0`. It was fixed several months ago and will be included in the next release, I suppose.

Anyway, if you don't want to wait for that to happen, just go [here](http://androidplot.com/download/), download latest development version, which, as for now, is `Androidplot 0.6.1` and replace your old library jar with the new one.

After that it should work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Looking forward for the new release. When will it come?

Answer (score 1):

What I did

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    PieChart graficoPartidos = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.mySimplePieChart);
        graficoPartidos.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);

        Segment seg0 = new Segment(" ", 0.0);
        Segment seg1 = new Segment(" ", 10);
        Segment seg2 = new Segment(" ", 10);

        graficoPartidos.addSeries(seg0, new SegmentFormatter(Color.rgb(106, 168, 79), Color.BLACK,Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
        graficoPartidos.addSeries(seg1, new SegmentFormatter(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0), Color.BLACK,Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
        graficoPartidos.addSeries(seg2, new SegmentFormatter(Color.rgb(255, 153, 0), Color.BLACK,Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK));
    PieRenderer pieRenderer = graficoPartidos.getRenderer(PieRenderer.class);
        pieRenderer.setDonutSize((float) 0 / 100,   PieRenderer.DonutMode.PERCENT);
    }
```

and what I get

[image]

Its working,I dont see any problem .

Comment: Its working only if you have two numbers. Uf you have only one doesnt show anything

Comment: @DejaVu Sorry, then probably u should use achartengine .